# What to return in this recursive method?

Tags: android, kotlin, recursion, arraylist, return

I'm creating a method to recursively search for a `View` inside an `ArrayList`. It will loop through this `ArrayList` and, if it contains an `ArrayList`, it will be searched for `View`s too, and so on, until finding a `View` to return. This is so I can make whatever `View` is inside there invisible.

```
fun searchForView(arrayList: ArrayList<*>): View {
    arrayList.forEach { item ->
        if (item is View) {
            return item
        } else if (item is ArrayList<*>) {
            item.forEach {
                searchForView(it as ArrayList<*>)
            }
        }
    }
} // Error here, needs to return a View
```

So I will use it like this:

```
someArrayList.forEach {
    searchForView(someArrayList).visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

However it is giving me an error because there needs to be a `return someView` statement near the end of the method. Whenever I call it, the `ArrayList` being searched will *always* have a `View`. **So what should I be returning here at the end, knowing that whatever `View` found will already be returned?**

Comment: Is there any change of muliple view in `someArrayList` then which one should return ?

Comment: Oh, right. I added a `forEach` now, so it'll loop through each `someArrayList`'s items to search for Views to make invisible.

Comment: rather you can make view INVISIBLE inside searchForView see solution below

Comment: not an answer to the question, but should be `searchForView(item)` instead of `item.forEach { searchForView(it as ArrayList<*>) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set inside function and don't return anything

```
fun searchForView(arrayList: ArrayList<*>){
    arrayList.forEach { item ->
        if (item is View) {
            item.visibility = View.INVISIBLE // set here
        } else if (item is ArrayList<*>) {
            item.forEach {
                searchForView(it as ArrayList<*>)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should  use `searchForView(item)` instead of `item.forEach { searchForView(it as ArrayList<*>) }` as @IR42 suggested since you don't know each item in arraylist is an arraylist or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing like you before
and this is what I've made

```
class VisibilitySwitcher(private val mutableViewSet: MutableSet<View?>, private val onCondition: Boolean = true){
    fun betweenVisibleOrGone(){
        if(onCondition)
            mutableViewSet.forEach {
                when (it?.visibility) {
                    View.VISIBLE -> {it.visibility = View.GONE}
                    View.GONE -> {it.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
                }
            }
    }

    fun betweenVisibleOrInvisible(){
        if(onCondition)
        mutableViewSet.forEach {
            when (it?.visibility) {
                View.VISIBLE -> {it.visibility = View.INVISIBLE}
                View.INVISIBLE -> {it.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
            }
        }
    }

    fun betweenInVisibleOrGone(){
        if(onCondition)
        mutableViewSet.forEach {
            when (it?.visibility) {
                View.INVISIBLE -> {it.visibility = View.GONE}
                View.GONE -> {it.visibility = View.INVISIBLE}
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> Usage Example

```
class LoginActivity : BaseActivity() {

    @Inject
    @ViewModelInjection
    lateinit var viewModel: LoginVM

    private lateinit var mutableViewSet: MutableSet<View?>

    override fun layoutRes() = R.layout.activity_login

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        facebookBtn.setOnClickListener { handleClickEvent(it) }
        googleBtn.setOnClickListener { handleClickEvent(it) }
    }

    private fun handleClickEvent(view: View) {
        when (view) {
            facebookBtn -> { viewModel.smartLoginManager.onFacebookLoginClick() }
            googleBtn -> { viewModel.smartLoginManager.onGoogleLoginClick() }
        }

        mutableViewSet = mutableSetOf(facebookBtn, googleBtn, progressBar)
        VisibilitySwitcher(mutableViewSet).betweenVisibleOrGone() // <----- Use without Condition
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        VisibilitySwitcher(mutableViewSet, resultCode != -1).betweenVisibleOrGone() //<-- Use with Conditions
        viewModel.smartLoginManager.onActivityResultCallBack(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

The point is whenever you click login from facebook or google button
It will set visibility for facebook and google to be gone and set progressbar(the default of progressbar is View.GONE) to be visible

At override fun onActivityResult()
if the resultcode is not -1 it means that it got some error or cancel
so it will switch back the progressbar to be gone and change facebook and google button to be visible again

> If you want to fix your own code I would do this

```
fun searchForView(mutableViewSet: MutableSet<View?>){
        mutableViewSet.forEach {
            when (it?.visibility) {
                View.VISIBLE -> {it.visibility = View.INVISIBLE} 
                View.INVISIBLE -> {it.visibility = View.VISIBLE} //<-- you can delete this if you don't want
            }
        }
    }
```

> Or very short form

```
 fun searchForView(mutableViewSet: MutableSet<View?>) = mutableViewSet.forEach { when (it?.visibility) {View.VISIBLE -> it.visibility = View.INVISIBLE } }
```

> Usage

```
val mutableViewSet = mutableSetOf(your view1,2,3....)
searchForView(mutableViewSet)
```

> if it has to use arrayList: ArrayList<*> Then

```
fun searchForView(arrayList: ArrayList<*>) = arrayList.forEach{ if (it is View) it.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not compileable because it's supposed to return a View, but you aren't returning a View in the `else` branch or if you reach the end of the input list without finding a View.

However, if all this function does is return a View, then it is not usable for your requirement to set *all* views' visibility. It would only return a single View.

Instead, you can pass a function argument for what to do to each view it finds. There's no need to return anything.

```
fun ArrayList<*>.forEachViewDeep(block: (View) -> Unit) {
    for (item in this) when (item) {
        is View -> block(item)
        is ArrayList<*> -> item.forEachViewDeep(block)
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
someArrayList.forEachViewDeep {
    it.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

If it's very deeply nested, you might want to rearrange this function to be tail-recursive like this:

```
tailrec fun List<*>.forEachViewDeep(block: (View) -> Unit) {
    for (item in this) {
        if (item is View)
            block(item)
    }
    filterIsInstance<ArrayList<*>>().flatten().forEachViewDeep(block)
}
```